# Divider between category in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I'm trying to achieve Settings app look, which means I'm looking for solution to add divider between categories.

[image: Settings]

So I thought I found solution, but unfortunately it's not working for me. As was suggested I should add empty preference with layout:

```
</PreferenceCategory>
    <Preference
        android:title="Test"
        android:summary="Summary"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

<Preference layout="@layout/divider_preference" />

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Category"/>
```

Here is divider:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="10dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But what I get is just empty preference:

[image: My]

So how could I fix that?

Comment: Dividing line between preferences category.

Comment: Picture above from settings app shows exatcly what I want

Comment: Did you achieve they above layout?  Can you include your shadow backgrounds to give a complete solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout="@layout/divider_preference"
        android:title="Category1">

    <Preference
        android:title="Test"
        android:summary="Summary"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout="@layout/divider_preference"
        android:title="Category2">

    <Preference
        android:title="Test1"
        android:summary="Summary1"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I added empty preference category between my categories with @layout/divide_preference, but I gave me hint. Thank you !

Comment: This does not work for me, "@layout/divider_preference" cannot be resolved. For some reason, this is not defined. I am using PreferenceFragment...